# how to display data in tables with alternate row colour

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display data in tables using alternative colour schemes for rows.

I am using the code below to display to results.

```
<?php 


      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  {
          echo "<tr> ";
           echo "<td>" .$row[username] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" .$row[total] . "</td>";
         echo "</tr> " ;
}

?>
```

I want to use this format for displaying data:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="alt"><td>Data</td><td>points</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data</td><td>points</td></tr>
<tr class="alt"><td>Data</td><td>points</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data</td><td>points</td></tr>
<tr class="alt"><td>Data</td><td>point</td></tr>

</tbody>
```

Kindly guide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use css:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

This fiddle shows how you can select `even`, `odd`, every `n'th`, or every `n'th + x` row to style it, with just CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/zhd66arb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo operator:

```
<?php
  $rowNum=0; 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  {
      echo "<tr ";
      if ($rowNum++ % 2 == 0) {
          echo 'class="alt"';
      }
       echo " >";
       echo "<td>" .$row[username] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" .$row[total] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr> " ;
  }
```

Comment: same result are original query

Comment: @aleksay , i want to use this query for multiple tables. and rows range from 5 to 30+.

Answer (score 0):

try as shown below

```
<?php 

      $i = 0;
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  {
      $class = "";
      if($i % 2 == 0)
          $class = "class='alt'";
      echo "<tr $class> ";
         echo "<td>" .$row[username] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" .$row[total] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr> " ;
      $i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter:

```
$i = 1
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<tr" . (($i++%2) ? '' : ' class="alt"') . ">";
    echo "<td>" .$row[username] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row[total] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr> " ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to obtain the remainder of dividing `$rowNum` by 2. Basically, for every row, add one to `$rowNum`, then check to see if it's even or odd. Also, make sure that you add quotes to `username` and `total`. Since you didn't enclose them in strings, they were being treated as constants.

```
<?php
$rowNum = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  {
    echo ($rowNum++ % 2 == 0) ? "<tr class=\"alt\">" : "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['total'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: same result as original query of mine

Comment: @user3500806 Mine is slightly different. I changed the first line of the while loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use a count variable to count the loop then use count%2 to get every other iteration.

```
<?php 

  $count = 0;  //The count variable
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  {

     echo "<tr" // open the tag

       if($count%2 == 0) {
          echo "class='alt'"; // Ever other iteration, this will run
       }

     echo ">"; // close the tag
     echo "<td>" .$row[username] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" .$row[total] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr> " ;
}

?>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';'